# How to have a batch call another batch based on its location?

Tags: windows-8, batch-file

I have made a file I will put up for download. It involves one batch file calling another.

Most of the time this is not a problem, but in my case I have no clue where they will download it. So how can I make the first batch file find its location and use it's location to call the second.

Both batch files are in the same folder.

Thank you.

Comment: Do you mean, you need to pass the file path of downloaded file as an argument to the second batch file? Also, is the batch file being invoked automatically or by the user?

Comment: The user will start the 1st Bach then the Bach will run and call 2ed bach which is in the same folder as the first. The first bach is a disclamer and terms of use and the 2ed is the is the program.

Comment: Say Bach 1 is in.\…\…\hi after Bach 1 is done it will call .\…\…\hi\Bach 2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Batch file name itself (with full path) is available as parameter 0. Together with modifiers, it allows you to extract the path:
`echo "%~dp0"` will just print it, but of course you may use it wherever you want (ie concatenate with second batch name and call).
`%0` is parameter 0
`~` is modifier 'escape' (it also removes quotes)
`d` is drive letter
`p` is path.
You may also use other modifiers, see here: http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/percent.mspx?mfr=true

Comment: So use echo"%~dp0"\Bach2 insted of something like c:\…\…\…\hi\Bach2?

Comment: use "%~dp0\Bach2" (or "%~dp0Bach2" as expanded path includes \\) instead of c:\…\…\…\hi\Bach2. Quotes are there in case there are spaces in the path